# How to determine gradient field of vectors with one degree of freedom?

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

I have a three-dimensional meshgrid, where in each point of the grid, I have a vector $v$ with one degree of freedom.
What I know about this vector field is:
$$v:=\nabla u$$
that it is supposed to be a gradient field.
I also know the values of $u$ at one boundary.

The problem is that I do have these vectors in each point but they have all a degree of freedom and I don't know if there is a way to fix or determine all vectors to form a gradient field.

Comment: Gradient fields always have zero curl. That might fix the value of the degree of freedom.